# Create new object from existing array and object

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to return a new object with properties given in the existing object and keys present in a given array. I can't mutate the object and if the keys are present in the array but not in the object the key should be ignored. I get hung up on how to compare the array elements to the objects keys.

```
function picker(array, obj) {
    var newObj = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < arrary.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] !== obj[i]) {
            newObj[array[i]] = obj[i];
        }
    }
    return newObj;
}

var array = [
    'a',
    'c',
    'e'
];
var obj = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
    d: 4
};

var bubble = picker(array, obj);
console.log(bubble);   result --> `{ a: 1, c: 3 }`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably meant something like this:

```js
function picker(array, obj) {
  var newObj = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] in obj) {
      newObj[array[i]] = obj[array[i]];
    }
  }
  return newObj;
}
var array = ['a', 'c', 'e'];
var obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4};
console.log(picker(array, obj));
```

That is, if `obj` contains the property with name `array[i]`, then add that property to `newObj`.

Maybe it will be clearer if you iterate with `reduce`, `forEach` or `for...of`, then you won't be confused by the index `i`.

```js
function picker(array, obj) {
  return array.reduce(function(newObj, key) {
    if (key in obj) newObj[key] = obj[key];
    return newObj;
  }, {});
}
var array = ['a', 'c', 'e'];
var obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4};
console.log(picker(array, obj));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

```
const x = array.reduce((total, current) => current in obj ? ({
  ...total,
  [current]: obj[current]
}) : total, {});
```

Which basically creates an object, key after key, based only on items of the `array`, where the value per key is taken from `obj`. Check out [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/taxigy/8toj44ca/).

Answer (score 0):

You haven't checked whether the key is existing in the array.

The condition `if (array[i] !== obj[i]) {` is trying to check the array key with object value instead of object key. Also `obj[i]` is incorrect, since `obj[0]` does not exist with the key `0`.

This is another variation using `Object.keys` instead of `for` loop.

```js
function picker(array, obj) {
  var newObj = {};
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key){
    if(array.indexOf(key) > -1) {
      newObj[key] = obj[key];
    }
  });
  
  return newObj;
}
var array = ['a', 'c', 'e'];
var obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4};
console.log(picker(array, obj));
```